# AVAudioEngine (iOS 8 Obj-C): How to construct the graph for Recording & Playback?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, core-audio

I need to create the render graph for basic **recording to a file and playback from that file,** using *AVAudioFile & AVAudioInputNode.*

Below are the main setup methods I started, but the graph is connected just for player.

#### How do I construct the graph so that [Input], [Player] [Mixers] are connected to achieve Rec/Play?

```
#pragma mark - Setup
-(void)setupAudioEngine{

//create
_audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc]init];
_player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
_inputMixer = [[AVAudioMixerNode alloc]init];
_playerMixer = [[AVAudioMixerNode alloc]init];


//attach player to engine
[_audioEngine attachNode:_player];
[_audioEngine attachNode:_inputMixer];
[_audioEngine attachNode:_playerMixer];

_input = [_audioEngine inputNode];
_mainMixer = [_audioEngine mainMixerNode];

//setup audio file
NSError *error = nil;


//Connect the render grapth
[_audioEngine connect:_input to:_mainMixer format:[_input inputFormatForBus:0]];
[_audioEngine connect:_player to:_mainMixer format:_audioFile.processingFormat];



//Start the Engine
[_audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error];

 if(error)
 {
  NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 }

}

- (IBAction)recordAudio:(UIButton *)sender {

NSError *error = nil;

//setup for writing to a file
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                         @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                         nil];
 NSURL *inputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

 NSDictionary *recordSettings = @{
                               AVFormatIDKey : @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                               AVSampleRateKey : @44100.0f,
                               AVNumberOfChannelsKey : @1,
                               AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey : @16,
                               AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : @(AVAudioQualityMedium)
                               };


  _audioFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForWriting:inputFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

  [_mainMixer installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:4096 format:[_mainMixer outputFormatForBus:0] block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer, AVAudioTime *when) {

 }];

}

 - (IBAction)stopRec:(id)sender {
  [_audioEngine disconnectNodeOutput:_input];
 }

- (IBAction)playAudio:(UIButton *)sender {
 //schedule play
 [_player scheduleFile:_audioFile atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
 [_player play];
}
```

Comment: How do you know the graph is not connected properly?

Comment: No, in this above portion of code the graph is connected properly only for playback, but how do I connect the recorder & player? to intermediary mixer and then both to mainMixer? That's why I'm not sure how to construct the graph properly?
i.e. [Input/Mic] -> [mixer] -> [mainMixer]->[output] ?

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1: Not all bitrate/audioformat/samplerate combinations work. Most of them will crash, so stick to the ones that work (I discovered a few, empirically).

This code records and plays .M4A format:

```
func directoryURL() -> NSURL {
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        filepath = urls[0]
        let documentDirectory = urls[0] as NSURL
        print("STORAGE DIR: "+documentDirectory.description)
        //print("---filepath: "+(filepath?.description)!)
        let soundURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(m4aName) //.m4a
        print("SAVING FILE: "+soundURL!.description)
        return soundURL!
    }

    //INIT AUDIO RECORDER
    func initializeAudioSession(){
        let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(16000.0)),
                              AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)), //.m4a    !!
            //  AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFileMP3Type)),
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Low.rawValue)) ] //mp3 crashes!!

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

            try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: self.directoryURL(),
                                                settings: recordSettings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
            audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
            print("M4a Recorder Initialized - OK...")
            recordSpeechM4A();
            stopRecordingCapio();
        } catch let error1 as NSError{
            print("Init Error: "+error1.description)
        }
    }

    //REC SPEECH AUDIO IN .M4A format
    func recordSpeechM4A(){
        if !audioRecorder.recording {
            isRecording=true //optional variable for tracking
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do {
                try audioSession.setActive(true)
                print("**** RECORDING ****")
                audioRecorder.record()
//Animate a microphone waveform while the user speaks
                self.meterTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.03,
                                                                         target:self,
                                                                         selector:#selector(ViewController.updateWaveview2(_:)),
                                                                         userInfo:nil,
                                                                         repeats:false)


            } catch {
                print("RECORDING ERROR")
            }
        }
    }
    //STOP RECORDING
    func stopRecording(){
        audioRecorder.stop()
    }
    //PLAY
    func playRecordedAudio(){
        if (!audioRecorder.recording){
            do {
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioRecorder.url)
                audioPlayer.play()
                print("PLAYING AUDIO...: "+audioRecorder.url.description)
                print("Audio duration: "+audioPlayer.duration.description)
            } catch {
                print("AUDIO PLAYBACK ERROR")
            }
        }
    }
```